# Solve this linear system over the field $\mathbb F_7: 2x + 5y = 1, 3x + 4y = 6$

Tags: linear-algebra

I really have no idea how to go about this, because I'm not supposed to use Gaussian elimination. Please help.

Comment: Hint: In $\mathbb F_7$, we have that $5=-2$.

Comment: Guassian elimination would seem to indicate a system of equations, but this is only one. Are you sure this is the whole problem?

Comment: Hmmm you have that $x=(1-5y)2^{-1}=(1-5y)(4)=4-20y=4+y$, so I get $x=4+y$, but by the way you ask your question I feel there is something missing lol

Comment: Sorry, another eqn is missing.

Comment: Adding an appropriate multiple of the first equation to the second reveals the solution set immediately.  But that's pretty much GE, so I don't get why you were told to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

In $\mathbb F_7$, $5=-2$ and $4=-3$, so the first equation is $2(x-y)=1$, and the second is $3(x-y)=6$, or $x-y=2$, so $2(x-y)=4$. The system is inconsistent.